# How to set a column width of a gridview in android?

Tags: android, gridview

i'm using gridview in android and i want to set the first column's width but i could not. while i am trying to find the answer to the problem i came face to face with a comment as you can see below. My question is that is description below really true?

**All columns in a GridView have the same size.** 
On Sat, May 23, 2009 at 9:25 PM, solid  wrote:

> I am having trouble controlling the size of the columns in my 
>   GridView.  The first column is only 3-4 chars and the other 4 columns 
>   are 5-8 chars.  For some reason, all the columns are the same width, 
>   leaving a huge amount of spacing after the first column and wrapping 
>   the text inside the others.  Is there a way, I can set the width of 
>   individual columns in the grid view?  In an ideal world, gridview 
>   would work like an html table, where the smaller columns are shrunk to 
>   fit the data and larger columns expand as necessary.  Any ideas would 
>   be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly write in your layout resource file.

```
  android:columnWidth="100dp"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score -2):

try this may this helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much? android:columnWidth="90dp" is pretty much what OP asked for, is it not?

Comment: `android:columnWidth` sets a fixed width for **each** column, but the question is how to set the **first** column only