# Change the size of the first GridView column

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to achieve that the first column of my GridView is a bit wider than the other four:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the first column is not wide enough to display the whole date without a line break. Since there's some space left in the other four columns, I'd like to shrink them and give the first column a bit more width.

At the moment, I'm using an ArrayAdapter with a simple_list_item_1 und achieve my current result.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
testView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My XML for the GridView looks like this:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/testView"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

How do I solve that in a reasonable way?

**EDIT:** 
I don't want to change the size of all columns like in the possible duplicate. I just want to change the size of the first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a column width of a gridview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789121/how-to-set-a-column-width-of-a-gridview-in-android)

Comment: @NoumanCh The topic you mentioned haven't been solved satisfiable.

Comment: What is `simple_list_item_1`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov http://arteksoftware.com/androids-built-in-list-item-layouts/

Comment: @PeterPan, well, if it's the simplest form (i.e. only one value and title), then that means your list adapter doesn't have rows - which, considering that you _want_ to have table and rows, means that `TableLayout` suggested by Nourman **is** the thing which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make use of Span Size to get the required size of your column.

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 10); // 3 cols of 3 + 1 col of 1
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
  @Override
  public int getSpanSize(int position) {
    if (position % 4 == 3)
       return 1; // Fourth column is 1x
    else
       return 3; // Remaining columns are 3x
  }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

this is just an example of using span but not the solution of your scenario.

hope this will help you.